# Inheritance in Hibernate. Inserting example

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

I want to make connection between Product class and Laptop
Product class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal cost;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int count;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productStatus", nullable = false)
    private ProductStatus productStatus;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productManufacture", nullable = false)
    private ProductManufacture productManufacture;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productCategory", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory productCategory;
```

and
Laptop class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "laptops")
public class Laptop extends Product {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String processor;
    private int videoMemory;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int ram;
```

But my varient doesnt work...( How can I do it right
And how can I insert into database some data?(example please)

Answer (score 0):

Laptop is extending Product class and inherits all the fields from the parent class including ID. You are defining ID again on the Laptop class. Inheritance Strategy is also JOINED which means it handles the Id generation both for the parent and the child class. Remove the Id field and its annotations.

Comment: And what i  should to write instead JOINED?

Comment: Nothing. Joined strategy is working perfectly. You just have to alter the mapping